# How do you call a child protected method from the base class with dynamic

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, .net-4.5

Got the following code

```
 protected virtual void InternalChange(DomainEvent @event)
 {
       ((dynamic) this).Apply(@event);
 }
```

child objects implement the logic to handle events via a number of fields eg

```
 protected Apply ( Message1 message)
 {

 }
protected Apply ( Message2 message)
 {

 }
```

however this gives an error  saying its inaccessible. I tried virtual but no luck..

Any ideas ? .. hopefully without reflection like this method. ( eg http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidebb/archive/2010/01/18/use-c-4-0-dynamic-to-drastically-simplify-your-private-reflection-code.aspx)

More information  I can move the InternalChange to the child class but id rather not have  the child doing the dispatch.

```
   void Apply(AggregateRootHandlerThatMeetsConventionEvent domainEvent)
    {
        OnAggregateRootPrivateHandlerThatMeetsConventionCalled = true;
    }


    void Apply(AggregateRootPrivateHandlerThatMeetsConventionEvent domainEvent)
    {
        OnAggregateRootPrivateHandlerThatMeetsConventionCalled = true;
    }

    void Apply(AggregateRootProtectedHandlerThatMeetsConventionEvent domainEvent)
    {
        OnAggregateRootProtectedHandlerThatMeetsConventionCalled = true;
    }


    protected override void InternalChange(DomainEvent @event)
    {

        Apply(((dynamic)@event));
    }
```

Edit for now i'm using this in the child ( and made the parent abstract) which works but its ugly id rather implementers not worry about the dispatch .

```
    protected void Handle(DomainEvent message)
    {
        Handle ( (dynamic) message);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define your base class to have either `abstract` or `virtual` on the method signature, for instance.

```
protected abstract void Apply(Message1 message);
```

Use `virtual` if you want to define an implementation in your base class that doesn't have to (but can) be overridden in the child class.

In your subclass, you would override it as such:

```
protected override void Apply(Message1 message)
{
    // code here
}
```

Also, in your example, the method `InternalChange` is trying to call `Apply` with an argument of type `DomainEvent`, however, in both your overloads for `Apply`, they accept either type of `Message1` or `Message2`.  If it did compile, you would get a run time error anyway because the .NET dynamic run time would not be able to find an appropriate method that matches the argument.

As for using dynamic, I think it is unnecessary for the problem at hand.

Comment: Message1 and Message2 are of type DomainEvent thats the tricky part i need run time casting/overloading via dynamic... and thats also why i cant put the abstract method in the base class as i dont know the parameters implementers will use .

Comment: If `Message1` and `Message2` inherit from `DomainEvent`, you cannot upcast that direction implictly.  I'd recommend you use the keyword `as` to determine the actual type that gets sent to `InternalChange`.

Comment: But the code doesnt know the concrete type it comes from an event source DB... Sure i could make a case statement or use reflection but is there a better way ?

Answer (score 0):

The logic is sort of... reversed. I don't understand one or two things: what class is calling apply, the base type or the child type? How the discerning of the child class to send the event to happens? Couldn't you render Apply virtual protected and leave it empty in the base class?